# space auto add in input php

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a form to modify the data with the framework laravel 5.1, everything is ok, but when I submit the form, there are two input are added a space automatically

like this screenshot

[image]

there is my form

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
<input type="hidden" name="id_article" value="{!!$opusdef->id_article !!}">
<div class="td w10">
<input type="text" name="code_article" value="{!!$opusdef->code_article  !!}"  required/></div>
<div class="td w5">
<input type="text" name="num_activité" value="{!!$opusdef->num_activité !!}" required/>  </div>
<div class="td w15">
<input type="text" name="libellé_activité" value="{!! $opusdef->libellé_activité !!}" required/> </div>
<div class="td w5">
<input type="text" name="domaine" value=" {{$opusdef->domaine}}" required/></div>
<div class="td w10">
<input type="text" name="s_domaine" value=" {!!$opusdef->s_domaine!!}" required/></div>
```

my controller

```
 protected function  postAllOpusDef(Request $request){
   $data=$request->except('_token');

    $opusDefs=OpusDefs::where('id_article',$data['id_article']);
    if($opusDefs->update($data)){
        return redirect()->back()->with('status','donnée modifiée');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space in your value attribute.

Change:

```
<input type="text" name="domaine" value=" {{$opusdef->domaine}}" required/></div>
<div class="td w10">
<input type="text" name="s_domaine" value=" {!!$opusdef->s_domaine!!}" required/></div>
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="domaine" value="{{$opusdef->domaine}}" required/></div>
<div class="td w10">
<input type="text" name="s_domaine" value="{!!$opusdef->s_domaine!!}" required/></div>
```

---

Besides that, the user might still post a space? So you probably want to sanitize the user input prior to storing your data in the database.

Optionally you can create a middleware to transform the post data, much like how `Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` works.

Comment: Hi, Do you know how to catch the TokenMismatchException? I've already add the csrf_token in my form, but sometimes I get still this error, so I need to back to the page and refresh manually, so I want to make it auto @Robert

Comment: The csrf token is stored in the user session and is generated per request.  If you get a mismatch during dev, that usualy means the token is no longer available in the user session (or the token is incorrect). Check your session storage.

Comment: you are right, but I still have no idea how to do that, because I want to make the token available by refresh the page (I don't how to deal with it by other way) when it's not, so the client can not see the error page

Comment: I assume you are using file storage for the settings? Make sure that the web user is able to write in the storage path.

Answer (score 3):

here in the html only you put two space in the input value

```
<input type="text" name="domaine" value=" {{$opusdef->domaine}}" required/></div>
<input type="text" name="s_domaine" value=" {!!$opusdef->s_domaine!!}" required/></div>
```

remove this as

```
<input type="text" name="domaine" value="{{$opusdef->domaine}}" required/></div>
<input type="text" name="s_domaine" value="{!!$opusdef->s_domaine!!}" required/></div>
```